# 301 redirect from https to http on ONE link

Tags: .htaccess

I'd like to make a `301 redirect`, but only on one specific link:

```
http://www.example.com/example.html
```

in htaccess, Apache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: I don't see how this question is programming related. It is probably more suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on 
RewriteRule ^example\.html$ http://www.example.com/example.html [R=301,L]
```